# How to reconfigure zabbix-server?

Tags: zabbix

I have installed the ZABBIX from the sources, I need to be recompiling to add the --enable-java option.

Then I executed ./configure and make,but I don't known which executable file should be replaced in the installation directory，

I search the zabbix_server file in the unzip directory,

```
[root@zbx-flm zabbix-3.2.1]# find . -name zabbix_server -type f
./misc/init.d/freebsd/zabbix_server
./misc/init.d/fedora/core/zabbix_server
./misc/init.d/fedora/core5/zabbix_server
./misc/init.d/tru64/zabbix_server
./misc/init.d/suse/9.1/zabbix_server
./misc/init.d/suse/9.3/zabbix_server
./misc/init.d/suse/9.2/zabbix_server
```

These are just the startup files, not the binary files。So what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If these are unmodified sources and the compilation was successful, the server binary will be in the `src/zabbix_server` subdirectory.

Please note that the `--enable-java` flag does not modify the Zabbix server binary. Instead, Java gateway is built in `src/zabbix_java`. That is not a single binary anymore, though.

Comment: Thank you!So I just need to copy the src/zabbix_java to /usr/local/zabbix/sbin, is that so?

Comment: That is not a very maintainable solution, but as a quick test it should work, yes.